# Validate constructor parameters before construction

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor

im tryin to valide the constructor parameter before its constructed ,or else it doesnt construct.
Ill show only the relevant code snippets because there is several classes.

Heres the bool method :

```
public bool SetLocataire(Locataire personne )
    {
        if (personne.RevenuMens >= 3 * loyer)
        {
            locataire = personne;
            return true;
        }


        else
            return false;
            
    }
```

And the constructor:

```
 public Logement(int id, int nbpieces, double loyer, string adresse, Locataire locataire) {
        if (SetLocataire(locataire))
        {
            _id = id;
            _nbpieces = nbpieces;
            Loyer = loyer;
            _adresse = adresse;
            this.locataire = locataire;
        }

        else if(!SetLocataire(locataire))
            throw new ArgumentException("Revenus insuffisants");



    }

}
```

SetLocataire is working on its own, but not inside the constructor. Im a bit confused as to what to do after the condition is validated or unvalidated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In what way is it not working? By the way, you don't need to check it twice - you can remove the "if" part of your `else`.

Comment: Since `loyer` isn't passed to `SetLocaire`, one must assume it must be a field in the class, which won't have been set yet at the point you make the call in the constructor.

Comment: You set `locataire` in `SetLocataire` so no need to write `this.locataire = locataire;`. Also no need of `else if(!SetLocataire(locataire))` but just `else` to avoid call twice the method. Otherwise I don't see what the problem is. Also you don't check if null before accessing `.RevenuMens` (in case of being a class or nullable type)...

Comment: Slightly unrelated: What if `locataire` is `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
public Logement(int id, int nbpieces, double loyer, string adresse, Locataire locataire) {
    // Null Check
    if( locataire is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(locataire));
    // Sanity Check
    if( locataire.RevenuMens < 3*loyer ) throw new ArgumentException("Revenus insuffisants");

    // All Checks passed
     _id = id;
     _nbpieces = nbpieces;
     Loyer = loyer;
     _adresse = adresse;
     this.locataire = locataire;
}
```

---

btw probably the problem in your code:

```
public bool SetLocataire(Locataire personne )
{
    if (personne.RevenuMens >= 3 * loyer)
```

`loyer` is unknown in this scope. And if you were to use the Property `Loyer` it would have not been set, yet.

Comment: Indeed, i was using the getter Loyer before its been set. Thank you.